# Is Maven (3.0) and VSS (2005 version 8) a viable combination?

Tags: maven, visual-sourcesafe

Currently, I have a complex existing project using Visual Source Safe. I would like to change the build system to Maven and keep the source on VSS for now.

It seems that the links on Maven site to VSS are out of date (broken link) and searching on the internet for Maven and VSS did not provide me with much useful information.

Is Maven and VSS (2005 version 8) a viable combination? Any step by step guide available?

Many thanks

Comment: Maven is typically independent of the source control system, with the notable exception of the `maven-release-plugin`. Where do you see VSS and Maven interacting?

Comment: I was thinking to get the latest version of source code from within MVN POM so "mvn deloy" will do everything, and I don't have to create a script to first get source then run MVN. Just something nice to have, and I thought maven would support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check out code using Maven, the maven-scm-plugin has a [scm:checkout goal](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkout-mojo.html) . The [VSS implementation](http://maven.apache.org/scm/vss.html) is partial, so it might work for you.